# Max & Min Date in Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame, tmp_contracts, which looks like this:

```
     Trade Date    Futures
0     3/26/2004    K (May 04)
1     3/29/2004    K (May 04)
2     3/30/2004    K (May 04)
3     3/31/2004    K (May 04)
4     4/1/2004     K (May 04)
...
19416 03/11/2014   X (Nov 14)
19417 03/12/2014   X (Nov 14)
19418 03/13/2014   X (Nov 14)
19419 03/14/2014   X (Nov 14)
19420 03/17/2014   X (Nov 14)
```

I am trying to pivot this data frame so that I can identify the minimum and maximum trade date for a given contract, but this is not working intuitively:

```
In [517]: tmp_contracts.pivot_table(rows='Futures', aggfunc=[min, max]).head()
Out[517]: 

              min        max
Futures       Trade Date Trade Date
F (Jan 05)    Futures    Trade Date
F (Jan 06)    Futures    Trade Date
F (Jan 07)    Futures    Trade Date
F (Jan 08)    Futures    Trade Date
F (Jan 09)    Futures    Trade Date
```

I don't quite understand why this is happening this way.  Intuition would suggest, to me, that this would result in the minimum and maximum dates in the above dataset.  What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure why, but seems to work with np.min, np.max